# Java 8 - Find superclass reference is an instance of a subclass

Tags: java

I'm checking whether a superclass reference is an instance of a subclass, but couldn't make it work, not sure what am I missing.

SplitStrategy - Superclass
SplitByDC     - Subclass

strategiesList - is a list which contains the subclass instance.

```
//My existing code 
SplitStrategy strategy;
for (Iterator<SplitStrategy> strategyItr = strategiesList.iterator(); strategyItr.hasNext();     splitedList = strategy.execute((List) splitedList)) {
        strategy = (SplitStrategy) strategyItr.next();

        // Added below line to check for a subclass instance - this is returning false 
        if (strategy instanceof SplitByDC) { //Where SplitByDC is a subclass of SplitStrategy
```

Comment: You are forcing `strategy` to be a `SplitStrategy` by casting it.

Comment: Your code, though unidiomatic, looks like it should work. Show us a minimal code example we can run that gives us the error you're getting.

Comment: I'm not getting any error, it returns false.

Comment: What return false? You do not need cast `(SplitStrategy) itr.next()` If `strategiesList` is of `<SplitStrategy>`.

Answer (score 2):

see below for an example

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class CheckInstanceOf {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<A> alist = Arrays.asList(new A(), new B(), new B(), new C());
        for (A a: alist) {
            System.out.println(a.getClass().getSimpleName() + "  >> " + (a instanceof B));
        }
    }
}

class A {
}
class B extends A {
}
class C extends A {
}

CheckInstanceOf.main()
A  >> false
B  >> true
B  >> true
C  >> false
```